# How can draw tick related style like major tick, tick-length, position, color in react-google-charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

[image: le]

This picture can help to understand my problem. Need an orange tick.

Comment: there are no options that will do this for you, it will require some manipulation, both in the data and how the ticks are generated. both of which can be done dynamically. please share a sample of the code and data, currently used to draw the chart...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-montalcini-mh3hp?file=/index.js

Comment: If squares are close enough to your rectangular ticks, perhaps you could add a series to draw squares at the points you want.  See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points

Comment: maybe you should elaborate on what you actually need. I've already shown you how to draw the ticks, and the suggestion made by @dlaliberte will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

in the data table used to draw the chart,
we can use a hidden series with an annotation role.

```
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y');
data.addColumn('number', 'hidden series');
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
```

we use a value of zero for the hidden series.
this will place the annotation on the x-axis.
and we give the annotation a value, such as `'A'`, so the annotation is drawn.

to draw the *orange tick*, and hide the annotation value,
we use the following annotation options...

```
annotations: {
  boxStyle: {
    fill: '#f57c00',
    stroke: '#f57c00',
    strokeWidth: 1
  },
  stem: {
    length: 0
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 16
  },
},
```

you can use `fontSize` to change the size of the annotation.

to prevent the hidden series from being drawn,
we use the following options...

```
series: {
  1: {
    color: 'transparent',
    visibleInLegend: false,
    enableInteractivity: false
  }
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addColumn('number', 'hidden series');
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
  data.addRows([
    ['2010-01-01', 10, 0, 'A'],
    ['2012-01-01', 4, 0, 'A'],
    ['2014-01-01', 26, 0, 'A'],
    ['2016-01-01', 50, 0, 'A'],
    ['2018-01-01', 75, 0, 'A']
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      boxStyle: {
        fill: '#f57c00',
        stroke: '#f57c00',
        strokeWidth: 1
      },
      stem: {
        length: 0
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: 'transparent',
        fontSize: 12
      },
    },
    chartArea: {
      left: 80,
      top: 56,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 80,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        color: 'transparent',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
      }
    },
    title: 'value vs. Date',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'value'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

another option is to draw square points at each tick location,
as suggested by @dlaliberte

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addColumn('number', 'tick series');
  data.addRows([
    ['2010-01-01', 10, 0],
    ['2012-01-01', 4, 0],
    ['2014-01-01', 26, 0],
    ['2016-01-01', 50, 0],
    ['2018-01-01', 75, 0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 80,
      top: 56,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 80,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        color: '#f57c00',
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointSize: 12,
        pointShape: 'square',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
      }
    },
    title: 'value vs. Date',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'value'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: In the case when chart ticks are auto-generated (not taken from other series) then the position of the orange tick will be wrong.

Comment: you can add rows specific for the ticks, while leaving the values for the other series `null`

Comment: ticks are auto-generated

Comment: unfortunately, you won't be able to auto-generate the orange ticks